# How to insert new row b/w existing rows in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to insert new row b/w existing row,But getting error
My DB

```
RoutePoint      lat              lon                   type
    1      12.9061170343075     77.5724397120948        s 
    2      12.9209711117095     77.5601544553814        v
    3      12.892986142953      77.4662127668475        v
    4      12.9215410271329     77.5607713634547        s
```

Query-

```
String query1 = "UPDATE mytable SET RoutePoint = 
    RoutePoint + 1 where id > 3 "+"insert into rp(lat, lon,type) values (?,?,?)"; 

pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query1); // create a statement
pstmt.setDouble(1, 12.34234234);
pstmt.setDouble(2, 77.423423423); // set input parameter 2
pstmt.setString(3, s); // set input parameter 3
pstmt.executeUpdate(); // execute insert statement
```

But I'm getting error-

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
insert into rp(lat, lon,type) values (12.921343123349597,77.5601659236431,'s')
at line 1
```

Please help.

Comment: Not clear what exactly you are trying to do ? What is the logic of `UPDATE mytable SET RoutePoint = RoutePoint + 1 where id > 3 `

Answer (score 0):

In `query1` you have an UPDATE and an INSERT, these are two statements. You should separate them with some separator char or execute them one after the other (using two `PreparedStatement`s).

Comment: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).

Comment: If the statement (your UPDATE) has no parameters, then set no parameters when using it.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `Update` and the `Insert` commands simultaneously? Split your commands into two blocks:

Update:

```
String query1 = "UPDATE mytable SET RoutePoint = 
    RoutePoint + 1 where id > 3; 

pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query1); // create a statement
pstmt.executeUpdate(); // execute update statement
```

Insert:

```
query1 = "insert into rp(lat, lon,type) values (?,?,?)"
pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query1); // create a statement
pstmt.setDouble(1, 12.34234234);
pstmt.setDouble(2, 77.423423423); // set input parameter 2
pstmt.setString(3, s); // set input parameter 3
pstmt.executeUpdate(); // execute update statement
```